# How to find out if a download has finished?

Tags: c#, ssh

To download a file from a SSH Server via C#, I use `Renci.SshNet`.
The essential code is:

```
try
{
    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
    {
        sftp.Connect();                    

        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(localFileName))
        {
            sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, file);                      }
        }
        sftp.Disconnect();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    tbMessages.AppendText(ex.Message);
}
```

As the file size may be big, it takes an unpredictable time until the download has finished. But I must work with the downloaded file. How to find out, whether the download has finished or not?

Comment: Looks like you were missing a close "}", which I assume was a typo. What makes you think the download can continue after DownloadFile completes?

Comment: The closing brace has marched to the far east. But it is still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a synchronous call, then it will only return control to the calling method when the download has completed or an exception is raised.

Looking at the call to the DownloadFile method, it does not appear to be asynchronous as there's no callback method required, therefore the rather bland answer is that it will finish when it finishes; your code will continue from that line - although you'll need to close the brace on the

```
using (var file = File.OpenWrite(localFileName))
```

statement!

Comment: I have tested the code only with short files and saw a noticeable delay until the file's content appears in a text box. So I fear that this delay will grow to big extents if the file has a size of  several Megabytes.

Comment: Looking at their site, the SSH.NET library does have asynchronous functionality, this will essentially fire up the download on a separate thread, and you supply a method for it to callback, or return to, when the download has completed; meaning that your main thread is free in the meantime to take user interaction. Whether that's appropriate or suitable for your application is up to you - you might not appreciate someone moving page half way through a download meaning that the text box you want to populate isn't available when the download finishes...